# how to setsesion based on last registred id in codigniter model?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

After registration i need to redirect to user dashboard directly. I need to set session based on user role and last registered id. how to set this. already i have setsession function auth_model.php based on this i need to setsesion

```
function setUserSession($row=NULL)
 {
    switch($row->role_name)
    {
        case 'owner':

            $values = array('user_id'=>$row->id,'logged_in'=>TRUE,'role'=>'owner');
            $this->session->set_userdata($values);
            break;

        case 'employee':

            $values = array('user_id'=>$row->id,'logged_in'=>TRUE,'role'=>'employee');
            $this->session->set_userdata($values);
            break;  
    }

 }
```

i am doing registration using ajax and redirect using windows.location.href= "dashboard.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to setsession when we get the success status in php file. we need to set the session

```
 $this->session->userdata('last_generated_id')
select * from users where user_id =  $this->session->userdata('last_generated_id')
$row = $this->db->result();
 $this->auth_model->setUserSession($row);
redirect('logged_in_page');
```